# Separation of variables for Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Using separation of variables, find a set of solutions to the Laplace equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ on $\Omega=[0,a]\times[0,a]$ subject to the boundary conditions $u(x,0)=u(x,a)=u(x,y)=0$ for $x\in[0,a]$ and $y\in[0,a]$ and such that $u(0,y)=f(y)$ for $y\in[0,a]$. In particular, solve the case for which $a=1$ and $f(y)=4y(1-y)$

There's a lot to unpack here, and I don't think I know the steps to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abridged version is like this:

**Step 1:** consider the case $u(x, y) = f(x)g(y)$ and solve the Laplace equation (with the first three, zero boundary conditions) . Hint: you should get functions $\cos, \sin, \mathrm{cosh}, \mathrm{sinh}$ as $f$ and $g$.

**Step 2:** those solutions form an orthogonal family. If a series of them with some coefficients converge, the limit function is also a solution of Laplace equation. That means you want to find coefficients such that the sum of the series equals the given function ($4y(1-y)$) on the last peace of boundary. Turns out you can do it (hint: they are basically Fourier coefficients divided by something). 
Finally, you get a solution as a sum of the series of functions.

Comment: Hey, thank you for taking the time to write that. I still feel like I'm lost after reading your abridged version. Can you direct me to some resources (preferably a video) to help me further my understanding?

Comment: @Peetrius, http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LaplacesEqn.aspx seems like a good article. Example №1 is what you want basically. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to contact me here and I will try my best to explain.