# Solutions to the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the heat equation $u_t=ku_{xx}$ on the domain $\Omega=[0,1]$, subject to homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. Furthermore let $u(0,x)=f(x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$

If $f(x)=4\sin(2\pi x)$, find a solution to the equation

If $f(x)=4\sin(2\pi x)+12\sin(3\pi x)+3\sin(5\pi x)$, find a solution to the equation

If $f(x)=4x(1-x)$, find a solution to the equation

Currently, I have a solution to the first and last examples, but the second one is really giving me difficulties.

A solution to the first is $u(t,x)= 4\sin(2\pi x)e^{-4\pi kt}$

and the last is $u(t,x)= -\frac{32}{\pi^3}\sin(\pi x)e^{-\pi kt}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second example, find the solutions for functions $4\sin (2\pi x)$, $12\sin (3\pi x)$ and $3\sin (5\pi x)$ separately and then just take their sum.

You solution for the last example is incorrect. What you need to do is find the solutions $u_n$ for the problem for all functions $\sin(n\pi x)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then you need to write $f(x)$ as the series $\sum b_n \sin(n \pi x)$ (which is just Fourier series). It follows that the solution of the problem is just $\sum b_n u_n$ because it satisfies the heat equation as a sum of solutions and satisfies the boundary condition because we defined it like that.

You may notice that it's quite similar to you [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469382/separation-of-variables-for-laplace-equation).

Comment: That first part makes a lot of sense, and I was having a mental lapse trying to solve that problem. Thanks for that help. I'll continue my work and update answers.